# Starting page animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animation for my homepage when it first loads. I want the ball that I have to rise from the bottom of the page but once it goes to the middle the user to be able to click it and for it to expand to the whole page. I have the ball rising code which is here:

```css
*, *::after, *::before {box-sizing: inherit;}

html{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ball{
    background-color: #eb8c28; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    animation: rise;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rise{
    0%{
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    100%{
        border-radius: 50%;
        transform:translateY(-100%);
    }

    75%{
        border-radius: 40%;
    }

    80%{
        border-radius: 30%;
    }

    90%{
        border-radius:20%;
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(20,20);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ballcopy.css">
        <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
                <div class="ball"></div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I'm stuck on what to do for the scaling of the ball to the whole page. Should I create another div and have it be clickable or is there a way to create an animation that is clickable halfway to complete the animation using JS.

Comment: Hi, mind also sharing the html and place the relevant code in the snippet editor so viewers trying to help can reproduce from your current spot?

Comment: Just added the HTML, also edited the CSS to add the effect I want. When the expansion happens I want it to happen on click. I know it's not able to click halfway to expand through CSS animations. I would only be able to make it click at the beginning which is not what I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to add a class to the `ball` element (e.g. `click`), and then set a new animation to run once the class is set. It basically splits your original animation into two.

```js
// Get the ball element
let ball = document.getElementsByClassName("ball");
// First instance of the ball object, add a click listener.
ball[0].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  // add the click class
  ball[0].classList.add('click');
});
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball {
  background-color: #eb8c28;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  /* Added calc here to center the ball */
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  animation: rise;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.ball.click {
  animation: fill;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rise {
  0% {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes fill {
  0% {
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(20);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ballcopy.css">
  <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="ball"></div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlejandroVargas  Great! Can you upvote and mark the answer as accepted? There should be check mark underneath the vote count you can click on to accept the answer.